# Computer takes several hours to start after pressing the power on button

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, desktop-computer

For a while now my PC has been very slow to start up. I turn it off at night before going to sleep and when I try to turn it on in the morning it takes hours (roughly 2 to 4 hours). The computer does nothing at all for hours; the screen doesn't turn on and it just stays there nothing without at all happening. There is no sign of booting for 3 hours, then suddenly it turns on and starts working normally.

I've already tried to change the PSU and the problem persists. I am starting to think it's a motherboard issue. I also tried flashing the BIOS and the CMOS battery, but that did not work either.

System specs:

- 16 GB G-Skill RAM 1333 MHz
- Intel Core i7-3820 3.6 GHz (with Noctua cooler, the only for LGA2011)
- EVGA GTX 680 graphics card
- 900 W Corsair PSU (I do not remember all the specs of it)
- ASUS Rampage Extreme IV motherboard

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is it doing while it's starting?  What's on the screen?

Comment: Does it take time to show the BIOS or does the PC show the BIOS quickly but then it takes time to load Windows?

Comment: Do you have a external hard drive attached? If so, if you detach it does the computer boot fast?

Answer (score 6):

The Asus Rampage IV has a **Start** button for troubleshooting errors like this one :

[image: start button]

Shut down your computer, open the computer case and try to start the computer with the button on the motherboard.

If that works, the power button of your computer case is malfunctioning.

If it doesn't work, since you've already ruled out the PSU, the motherboard should be the culprit.

Comment: I don't think that necessarily narrows it down to the mobo.  He's not been clear about what the system is doing when it's starting.  The problem might be the hard drive, or some other component that's not initializing correctly, or even something stupid like a damaged SATA cable.

Comment: I answered assuming that *nothing* happens for a few hours. I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: +1 for the button, but if the wiring is faulty why would it _ever_ boot?

Comment: @terdon: I was thinking of a couple of scenarios where a wiring problem would aggravate other malfunctions, but one would only be possible with an AT case and the other would cause other issues as well...